# How to change the system timezone by WMI

Tags: c#, vbscript, timezone, wmi

I want to change the timezone of windows system by WMI.
But most articles about it on google just set the `CurrentTimeZone` property of `Win32_OperatingSystem` or `Win32_ComputerSystem`.

It will just only change the time,the name and others infomations about the timezone are not correct.

**Is there a typical sample to show how to set the timezone by WMI(C#/VBScript)?**